# Specific plugin for custom user information access?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, user-access

I've been looking for a while now, but I couldn't find anything near to what I need. Maybe I'm not using the right keywords, that's why I'm asking it here.

I need a plugin where the administrator is able to add custom information to users account. So when the specific user logs in he`ll be able to check the information.

Let`s say for example, each user has a field called Project Status, the admin may set the value for this field to "Completed", "Incomplete", etc...

I hope you guys may help me, and I appreciate any kind of help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Justin Tadlock has shown how to add custom fields to enhance User Profiles. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields - this can be further hacked to assign values as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Hi Kashif, thank you for your reply. Ok, looks like a fine solution, but I need those fields to not be edited by the user, only by the admin. Also it would be interesting having a separate page to show those fields, something like a custom dashboard.

Comment: I am sure any plugin developer can do that for you :)